# remove HTML from inside iframe using Javascript, not jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have an `<iframe>` that is added and removed from the stage as needed. Each time I add it, it needs to load a new page.

I need to get it to remove the previous contents so the frame is empty while the new page is loading.

Here is the code involved:

HTML:

```html
<div id='overlay' class='overlay'></div> 
<div id="overlay_displayer_wrapper" class="overlay_displayer_wrapper">
    <div id='overlay_displayer' class='overlayDisplayer'>         
    <iframe id='i_displayer' class='i_displayer'></iframe>     
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code that 'launches' the overlay and `iframe` above:

```js
function launchDisplayer(img_src, base_directory, session_pics){
showDisplayer(true);
document.getElementById( 'i_displayer' ).setAttribute( 'src', '' );
document.getElementById("i_displayer").src="feeder.php?call=main&curr=" + img_src + "&dir=" + base_directory + "&pics=" + session_pics;
}
```

This is the function `showDisplayer()`:

```
function showDisplayer(show){
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
var overlay_displayer = document.getElementById("overlay_displayer_wrapper");
if (show){
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    overlay_displayer.style.display = "block";
}else{
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    overlay_displayer.style.display = "none";

}
}
```

That's all the code involved in this action.

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the `src`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/9ZrMZ/

HTML:

```html
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://thinkingstiff.com"></iframe>
```

Script:

```js
document.getElementById( 'myframe' ).setAttribute( 'src', '' );
```

Comment: @LeeLoftiss What didn't work about it? Look at the demo. It does clear the iframe.

Comment: The contents are not clearing out like they do in your demo. Do you think adding and removing the iFrame through the style.display setting could be effecting it? Here is the project that is using it: http://projects.kleelof.com/shrinking_sensation/index.php

Comment: @LeeLoftiss I can't quite figure out from that link. Can you add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: Try adding `window.setTimeout( function () { /* your .src="feeder.php call goes here */ }, 3000 );` around your `... .src="feeder.php ...` call just to see if it's a timing issue.